# How to load module partly synchronously and partly asynchronously with webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have bunch of MDX pages that have frontmatter info in them. I want to use this data to build navigation which would be loaded synchronously, but actual pages should be loaded asynchronously. I have no problem with code splitting and I can extract frontmatter content in loader, but I'm not sure how to include this info in bundle without breaking async page load.

My guess is that I write plugin that will somehow collect this info and then will include it into bundle, and at this point I'm lost.

When should I tap into process with my plugin? How add all that info to final bundle and how to use that info in code?